# Is it possible to overwrite a clearfix with a <hr />?

Tags: html, css, clearfix

Currently, I have a clearfix wrapped around a large body of content. I have multiple sets of images on the left and text on the right with a `<hr />` under each. The only issue is that sometimes I don't have enough text to balance the image out, and so the `<hr />` gets pulled inline with the image. I need all the `<hr />` to be free of the clearfix, is this possible?

This is my clearfix:

```
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

The `<hr>`

```
hr {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 3.5rem;
  border-width: 0;
  border-top: 3px dashed #cacaca;
}

hr {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
}
```

My `<html>`:

```
<div class="main-wrap">
                   
<div class="clear-fix">
<h2>Title</h2>

<p class="content-image">
    <img src="http://example.jpg">
</p>

<h3>Title</h3>

<p>Example text.</p>
<hr />

<p><img src="http://example.png" /></p>

<h3>Example</h3>

<p>Lots of example text here.</p>

<hr />
```

This is what my HTML looks like right now.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you please include the HTML of the clearfix and the `<hr />` in question.

Comment: @DanielGibbs the clearfix was already included, but I added the hr for you as well

Comment: `hr{clear:both/* or left or right */}`  https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: @jonbon, you included the CSS; please include the HTML code, not a screenshot.

Comment: @GCyrillus this didn't work, some other part of my css must be breaking it or overriding it.

Comment: This is not caused by the clearfix. In fact, clearfix attempts to solve this exact problem! But you use it too late.

Comment: do the Images have custom `CSS`?

Comment: @DanielGibbs I added the html

Comment: doesn't a simple `hr{clear:both}` do the trick, or is this not what you want?

Comment: A poor solution would be, to just put some `<br>` tags on the text side. But it would definitively works.

Comment: @Christoph when I tried adding that earlier today, it didn't work, I'll try again... with !important

Comment: `class="clear-fix"`and  `.clearfix`do not match :( by the way

Comment: @GCyrillus thanks, I think  that was a typo on my part putting it up there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a "clearing" class that contains `clear: both;` to the `hr`:

(or add `clear: both;`  to the `hr` element itself)

```css
img {
  float:left; 
}

.clearing {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x200">
<hr class="clearing">
```

Comment: There was some additional hr that was also messing this up. I used this + a .specific-place hr{} and it fixed it